# Water dripping sound

Tags: water, heating

We just had our basement finished by professional contractors. Now we hear water dripping sound when the heat is on (We are in MI). This is how it sounds. When the heat first turns on, there is water dripping sound and it is relatively rapid (1/2 second in between?). Then the sound will be off after a while and the heat will keep running until the heat is off. Once the heat is off, the dripping sound will come back but at a much slower rate (5 seconds in between?). What could the cause be? I appreciate any input on this.

Comment: What kind of finishing was done? What kind of heat do you have (gas, electric, heat pump, etc.)?

Comment: Have you seen any dripping water?

Comment: It is a gas furnace and I do not see any dripping water.

Comment: Is it a "condensing" furnace? Is the furnace new as part of the basement work? Can you determine the location of the dripping sound? Is there a lavatory in the basement near the furnace? is there a floor drain? Is there a utility sink with 1-1/2" drain which has a side arm tailpiece under it? Is there a condensate drain going into a clothers washing machine drain?

Answer (score 2):

My guess it that it's metal duct work heating up (and expanding) when the heat first comes on, then contracting again when the heat turns off.  All of our houses that have had forced hot air have done this, and if this is what's going on, it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect the "ticking" sound you hear is metal duct work expanding and sliding against the brackets etc.  As the metal heats it expands, and this causes it to slide along the brackets, etc, that hold it in place.  Perfectly normal.

Comment: Can happen with pipe to, especially in an older house where pipe penetrations may be resting directly on the material they're passing thru. My hot water pipe does that in one spot, ticking regularly as it warms up and then again as it cools.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a high efficiency furnace, it will produce condensate water just like an air conditioner.  Check the drain(s).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Condensate water will be continuous during the heating cycle, which doesn't match what the question states is the observed behavior where there isn't the sound after things warm up.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a high efficiency gas fired furnace or water heater?

A high efficiency "condensing" gas fired furnace or water heater will extract so much of the heat from the exhaust gas stream that the water in the stream condenses to liquid. This condensate must be drained into the sewer. This condensate is drained into a lavatory drain or other drain and makes an audible dripping sound.

Comment: Condensate water will be continuous during the heating cycle, which doesn't match what the question states is the observed behavior where there isn't the sound after things warm up.

Comment: @Milwrdfan chances are you are correct, but there are report of sound from condensate dripping into lavatory drain and thought I would toss this out there as a possibility. Shudda been a comment not an answer. The plumbing supply I go to even stocks a threaded tailpiece (1-1/4" with smaller diameter sidearm) which is used for condensate drains under bathroom lavatories.

Comment: @Milwrdfan possibly a condensate drain could drip when the furnace first comes on and then become quiet as the flow increases to a stream as the volume of flow increases. Then when the burner turns off the flow decreases to the point dripping resumes. The OP needs to give us more info on the equipment and installation. Is this a condensing furnace? Can he locate where the dripping sound is coming from?

Comment: You are correct that more information is needed.  Identifying if the dripping sound is coming from the furnace area or elsewhere, along with what type of furnace the OP has would be helpful.  Maybe even a picture or two of the furnace would help so we could see if it is a condensing furnace and if so, how the condensate drain is routed.